Flutter Web App is not rendering if not visible
I have a question regarding rendering. I am deeply into optimizing Flutter Web, and so far, it has been working really well. By precaching and being meticulous about what and how to animate using CanvasKit, I've achieved great results. The only annoyance is the initial loading time.
My use case for Flutter Web is to integrate our app into other apps, so once loaded, loading times are no longer an issue. However, for the first load, I also want to make the experience as good as possible. Fortunately, I will embed our Flutter Web app into a tab view, so preloading and rendering should not be a problem, and everything should be ready by the time the user reaches the tab. The issue here is that Flutter Web does not render when it is not visible.
I've also observed this behavior on Chrome Desktop Browser. If I place the browser on another, non-visible desktop and start loading my Flutter Web App, it loads CanvasKit and MainDart.js but doesn't render any views until I return to the browser and make it visible. This is the same if I put my Flutter Web app into a not initally visible tab. It doesn't render till I am not showing the tab.
Does anybody have similar experiences and know the reason for this or even a solution?
